# Why does specifying a different folder name for `git` produce an error?

Tags: git, macos

I tried using the following line in Terminal on macOS El Capitan to clone my fork of the [calibre](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre) repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/chivalry/calibre.git opns.calibre
```

The `opns.` is simply part of my organization system for projects on my local computer (`clnt.` for client projects, `pers.` for personal projects, etc.). `opns.` is what I use for open source projects that I didn't create.

Anyway, the above line resulted in the following feedback:

```
2016-07-04 18:01:22.024 xcodebuild[834:15575] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XVim.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
Cloning into 'opns.calibre'...
remote: Counting objects: 264261, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -3629.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Having tried it twice, I tried the command without the destination folder name change and got the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/chivalry/calibre.git
Cloning into 'calibre'...
remote: Counting objects: 264261, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: Total 264261 (delta 42), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 264182
Receiving objects: 100% (264261/264261), 193.00 MiB | 965.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (211015/211015), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (5116/5116), done.
```

This isn't a huge deal, and it's not preventing me from doing anything, but it's odd. I've cloned GitHub repositories before using the exact same type of command, providing a destination folder that begins with `opns.`, without any trouble. In fact, after the clone was successful, I changed the name in the Finder without any apparent trouble (will this cause trouble later?).

So why did it error out twice this time? Given the error message, it has something to do with the XVim plugin that I have installed, but I don't understand what the problem might be.

Comment: Renaming the directory after the fact is fine; and I have no idea what went wrong, but perhaps it was just coincidence that it failed twice and then worked without the name-change.  I note that in your pasted text, the data transfer *was* working for a while (`... KiB/s`) and then overwritten with the error message (hard to tell if it's `error -36` or `error -3629`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

It must be an issue with the plug-in or some other unknown factor within your environment.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/chivalry/calibre.git opns.calibre
Cloning into 'opns.calibre'...
remote: Counting objects: 264261, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: Total 264261 (delta 42), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 264182
Receiving objects: 100% (264261/264261), 193.00 MiB | 912.24 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (211015/211015), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Running the same command in OS X 10.11.5 encounters no issues.